# How to get user mobile number in android using sim network?

Tags: android

I'm using this code, is there any other way to get the mobile number?

```
String mPhoneNumber=null;

TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TermsandConditionsActivity.this,
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TermsandConditionsActivity.this,
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TermsandConditionsActivity.this,
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    return;
}
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```